# Existing host keys found error when ssh in gcp vm instance , putty error: no supported authentication method available

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am getting the following error but some of my colleagues work just fine and ssh in without any issue.

Existing host keys found in /Users/xxx/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts